# System architecture : MVC app with microservices

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, architecture, microservices

We are trying to design our new system architecture where it'll be one front app with several services. The obvious approach was to follow the microservices architecture.

However, we would prefer not to opt for a frontend javascript framework for 2 main reasons :

- Requires to learn and master frontend frameworks
- Having to deal with security/tokens layer in the frontend

So we proposed the following architecture (microservices architecture minus front frameworks)

[image: Architecture]

Ex : When the user submits a form. The backend controller will request the REST service and then return the view with the adequate model

Now the question is : is this architecture worth it over a monolithic app ? Will it help to reduce overload on the main app when one of the services is overloaded ?

Comment: Usually the transition from the monolithic app to the microservices infrastructure comes after the current traffic patterns show a clear advantage to separate parts of the app out as microservices to reduce load on the main service and allow for independent scaling so I really think this depends on your actual usage.

Comment: Agree with the answer by David...don't go with microservices unless required...one critical factor is communication between microservices...if you require communication between them then it will add an overhead

Answer (score 1):

unless strictly necessary, don't overengineer your system and go for a monolith. Microservices are really needed either when :

- there are multiple Bounded Contexts, each one with one or more Aggregate Roots
- write/read patterns are quite different, possibly requiring different persistence storage mechanism

but even in those cases, it is definitely possible to design a good monolith and refactor it afterwards.

My suggestion is to get a very good understanding of the Domain, write an MVP and *then* refactor.

Comment: Actually, we have multiple independant databases. Some are heavy and critical (billions of records) while some more or less lightweight. I was wondering if it was better when the main app request a separate REST service or request the database directly.